# How do I make buttons that have the same transitions and some of the same properties, but then also have some differing properties?

Tags: html, css

So, I've barely done any design and am trying my hand at it, but I guess I'm thinking of things wrong when it comes to using class and id in my html and css since I'm thinking of it from a programming perspective. I was thinking of class as a sort of parent class and id representing a child, where they can inherit properties while at the same time having their own; however, though in some regard this seems to work, my transitions don't work as I expect them to when I hover over them.
I have an unordered list of buttons like this

```
<li><button  type = "button" id = "first">Press Me</button></li>
```

and this css:

```
button {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 24px;
    border-radius: 25px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear 0.2s;

    transition: all 0.2s linear 0.2s;
    }

#first{
    background-color:#ff9bcd;
    border: 5px double #ffffff;
}

#second{
    background-color:#ff9bcd;
    border: 5px double #9bffcd;
}

#third{
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

button:hover{
    background:#9bffcd;
    border: 5px dotted #ff9bcd;
    color:#9bffcd;
}
```

For first only the color transition works, for second only the border transition works, and for third only the background and color transitions work. It seems that the transitions only work for the properties I haven't overridden. Is there anyway of preserving these transitions while keeping their individual properties? I might override these transitions for other buttons, but I was just curious how I would go about maintaining it for some. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing reusable code always prefer to `class` rather that `id` which will help you to override the properties very easily and you don't have to be explicit.

So, here is example as you need. I think it will work for you.

HTML

```
<button  type="button" class="first">Press Me</button>
<button  type="button" class="second">Press Me</button>
<button  type="button" class="third">Press Me</button>
```

CSS

```
button {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 24px;
    border-radius: 25px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear 0.2s;

    transition: all 0.2s linear 0.2s;
}

.first{
    background-color:#ff9bcd;
    border: 5px double #ffffff;
}

.second{
    background-color:#ff9bcd;
    border: 5px double #9bffcd;
}

.third{
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

button:hover{
    background:#9bffcd;
    border: 5px dotted #ff9bcd;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ku6hv4rp/) .

Have a nice code day.

Answer (score 0):

Put the pseudo `:hover` selector to each button ID selector.

Try: `#first:hover { ... } #second:hover { ... } #third:hover { ... }`